# POST data not sent in IE 11 using the WebBrowser control

Tags: xmlhttprequest, webbrowser-control

I have the following JavaScript code being executed inside of an onclick event handler on my website.

```
var newRequest = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
newRequest.open('POST', '/index.cfm', true);    
newRequest.send('q');
```

If I use IE 11 and open up my web page that is located on a testing server I can see that the request gets sent as expected using Fiddler with a content length of 1 and 'q' in the post data. However, if I open up my application that hosts the WebBrowser control and navigate to the same website on my test server and have it execute the above code I can always see that the request is being made but that the Content-Length header is 0 and 'q' is not sent along with the request. Here is the failing request as it appears in Fiddler.

```
POST http://test.mycompany.com/index.cfm HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://test.mycompany.com/Curtis/BrowserTests/BrowserEventTests.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: test.mycompany.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

If I then set the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry value for my executable to 9000 then it works and does send the post data as expected.

Here is the correct request as reported by Fiddler.

```
POST http://test.mycompany.com/index.cfm HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://test.mycompany.com/Curtis/BrowserTests/BrowserEventTests.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: test.mycompany.com
Content-Length: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

q
```

If I change that value back to 10000 or 11000 then it does not work. Does anyone have any ideas on why the post data would not be sent properly using the WebBrowser control? I have reset my IE settings back to factory default with no change in behavior.

**Update:** If I change the JavaScript to look like this instead then it works with the emulation mode set to 10000.

```
var newRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
newRequest.open('POST', '/index.cfm', true);
newRequest.send('q');
```

Is this just a bug that needs to be reported?

Comment: I'd report this as a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/

Comment: I have narrowed it down further by noticing that the problem goes away if I return INET_E_USE_DEFAULT_PROTOCOLHANDLER in the Start method of the Protocol Handler. I have stepped all the way through the protocol handler code when the request is sent out correctly (Emulation set to 9000) and when it is incorrect (Emulation set to 10000 or above) and everything appears to behave exactly the same. The post data is given to my protocol handler using the IInternetBindInfo interface and is handed back to the web browsers code in the same way as far as I can tell.